# Azure AD Authenticate from API with username/pw - no UI, is there an example?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm attempting to set up a .net core API that can be given a username / pw, and authenticate to Azure AD with those credentials and return a JWT to the user for future requests.  This all needs to be 'behind the scenes', but every example I can find within Microsoft documentation involves some interface.

I've found examples with a web api that redirects you to the login page in the browser, and there's a console app example that goes directly to Azure AD (thus it needs the Azure info within it) and then gets a token for a separate API.  I don't want the consumer of the API to need any Azure info, they only need their user/pw credentials.

At the end of this setup, I should be able to use Postman to hit my own API with a username/pw, the API talks to Azure, authenticates, returns a JWT to my API which I pass back to the user.  The user uses that JWT for future requests to the API.  I haven't been able to find any samples like this :(

The API already supports the web interface redirect to Azure login page workflow,  I'm using that for a react app and it's all wired up nicely, but now I need to support other services consuming the API.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow.
It is supported by Azure AD, but it is highly discouraged to use.
See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) for api reference. 
And a mini example [here](https://joonasw.net/view/ropc-grant-flow-in-azure-ad)

Comment: This is perfect and I'll probably use it, because the use case does seem to fit. But just in case, is there some other way an outside service can authenticate with Azure AD without needing all the Azure tenant details?

Comment: Sure, Azure AD has perfect support for OpenId Connect. It is browser based, so it does not fit your current need. Asp.net Core 3 released today, with integrated Identity Server, so you should have no problem implementing this flow.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a solution that isn't browser based.  If I couldn't do it with postman it wouldn't really fit the need.

Comment: Then ROPC is the solution for you

Comment: @Alex you can use [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi) to help you achieve what you need using **Client Credential Flow**.

Comment: Client Credentials Grant Flow is used by clients to obtain an access token outside of the context of a user. The client cannot act on behalf of the user in this case.

Comment: Using ROPC is often a bad idea. You should never be handling user passwords if possible. Note also that it won't work e.g. if the user has MFA.

Comment: It's looking like ROPC isn't going to work anyway, because it seems to require that the Azure AD application is configured as a native-client, but a web api needs to be a confidential-client, so I can't do both of these within the same application.  I think I will need to have the client use the tenant information to get a token separate from the API.  Not what I wanted but seems like I don't have a choice now.